# POST values from different Forms

Tags: php

I have form in my index.php that gets a value of name. In my action.php, I need to display the value using $_POST['name']. The name displays well when I directed into action.php However, I have another form in action.php that when I `submit` that form and refreshed action.php, the displayed name says an **undefined index error** for displaying name.

```
include('connect.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;

echo '<form  method="get">';
     //...
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />';
echo '</form>';'
```

Comment: You are using the GET method while you should be using the POST method instead.

Comment: Does the second form have a `name` field? You only show the `submit` button.

Comment: @Barmar, even if I only have the submit button, when it's clicked, the error still occurs.

Comment: If there's no `name` field, `$_POST['name']` won't be populated and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the GET method while you should be using the POST method instead.
Change the following line:

```
echo '<form  method="get">';
```

To:

```
echo '<form  method="post">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that `$_POST['name']` is set using `isset()`:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['name']` is set. But when I submit the form in display.php it is not set.

Comment: @user3384012: That's why you check it, for when it is not set.

Comment: When form is submitted, it's when `name` is not set or becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

For you to call $_POST['name'] from a form on a previous page, you will need to use `form method = "GET" action = "targetpage.php"`

Answer (score 0):

use $_REQUEST["name"] it works for POST and GET Requests.

b.t.w. You should not echo Input data directly!! This can easily be used to do XSS Attacks. Use https://www.php.net/htmlentities or something like that before echoing a input directly to the browser! Otherwise a attacker could use something like alert('hax0rt'); as name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
include('connect.php');
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
echo $name;


echo '<form  method="post">';
     //...
    echo '<input type="text" name="name"><br><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />';
echo '</form>';'
```